# specifying Column Length for columns of @Type(type=xxx)

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hsqldb, dbunit

In order to remove few special characters coming from my host database tables into my application, I had to create my own datatype.

```
@Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY", nullable=false, length=24)
@Type(type="com.xx.CleanedString")
public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
    return this.lastUpdatedBy;
}
public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
    this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
}
```

`CleanedString` implements `UserType` whose `sqlTypes()` is defined as an `int[] { Types.CHAR }`. Basically it rebuilds String after iterating the char array and filtering it out the special characters.

```
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.CHAR };
}
```

Application works perfectly fine but I am having problem running my `DBUnit`. When Hibernate creates the table in HSQLDB (I have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to `create-drop`), it is creating a column of type `CHARACTER` with length as 1. It is ignoring the length attribute of my `@column` specified 24 above.

Is there a way to specify column length in this scneraio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting it to [`Types.VARCHAR`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#VARCHAR)

Comment: It works fine during Table creation in hSQLDB but what happens when it interacts with DB2 database's Character(n) data type which is not a varchar data type.